# How can I add a column with its values from one table into another table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this question has been probably asked a million times, but I can't seem to find what I do.
I have this table called Customer that only has 1 attribute (id)

```
      id
      ----
       1
       2
       3
       4
       5
```

And I have another table called Names that also has one attribute (name)

```
      name
      ----
       Tom
       Bob
       Sam
       Angel
       Joe
```

I want to add the column name from table Names to the table Customer so it turns out like this

```
       id  | name
      ------------
       1     Tom
       2     Bob
       3     Sam
       4     Angel
       5     Joe
```

How can I do this in sql?

Comment: What links the value from your table `Customer` to the table `Names`? Why does `Angel` have an `id` of `4`, and not `1`, for example?

Comment: There is no link. I just want to put them together for testing reasons

Comment: So it doesn't matter which is linked to which? If so, Gordon's answer will work for you, as which ID each name gets will, effectively, be random.

Comment: But I don't want it to be randomized though. Like, they don't really have a relation, but I want them to be linked in order.

Comment: Then there ***is*** a link. So, back to my original question: "*What links the value from your table `Customer` to the table `Names`? Why does `Angel` have an id of `4`, and not `1`, for example?"* We *need* to know the rules for that link first, and I can see no way to guarantee that in your very small data set.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do this:

```
alter table customer add column name nvarchar(255);

with toupdate (
      select c.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from customer c
     )
update toupdate
    from (select n.*, row_number() over (order by select null) as seqnum
          from names n
         ) n
    where toupdate.seqnum = n.seqnum;
```

Note that the order of the match **is not guaranteed**.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "default" ordering with a column specifying the ordering.  And in one column tables, you don't have such a column.

Comment: Is there no way for them to be linked in order?

Comment: @RubaSbeih as Gordon says *"SQL tables represent unordered sets."* There is no "order", so there is no order to preserve.

Comment: If your table `Names` was "ordered", @RubaSbeih , it would need a `CLUSTERED INDEX`. Considering that the table `Names` only has 1 column, then that order by have to be on the column `name`; meaning that the "first" name in the table would be `Angel` and the "last" `Tom` (or vice versa if the index is sorted in descending order). This would mean that `Angel` *should* have either the value `1` or `5` for `id` and certainly not `4`.